# How to get duration value from windows media services 9

Tags: windows-media-player, windows-media-services

I'm using windows media services 9 to provide streaming service and would like to make sure users can only play within specified interval to prevent abuse. The media server reads  and  from asx file and the player can start and end at the correct offset. I can get the start offset at AuthorizePlayEvent using

```
IWMSContext.GetQwordValue(WMSDefines.WMS_PRESENT_START_TIME,WMSDefines.WMS_PRESENT_START_TIME_ID, out dec, 0);
```

But I'm having problem getting the duration or end offset. I know windows media server writes log that contains c-starttime and x-duration. But the x-duration here doesn't seem to be what I want. I like to detect the  that gets passed from asx file at either AuthorizeOpenEvent or AuthorizePlayEvent. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to fetch WMS_PRESENT_DURATION_LO and WMS_PRESENT_TOTAL_PLAY_TIME_LO from IWMSContext on my 32-bit windows machine, but the result doesn't reflect the duration or end offset I like to get.

Comment: I found a post,http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-media-server/1004/limit-the-duration-of-multiple-connected-clients, described exactly what I tried to do. I also don't like to go for the heartbeat solution. Any better idea? Thanks!

Comment: ok. I'm now trying to get playlist as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd892922(v=VS.85).aspx so I can get ElapsedSimpleTime from the player. However, I'm getting error: The type 'MSXML.IXMLDOMDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Interop.MSXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own synchronized dictionary to keep track of active players at every heartbeat and disconnect player that exceed specified interval. I spent around 2 days looking for build-in server side parameters and was surprised to find nothing is available reliably.